# i am always getting segmentation fault

Tags: c++, memory, segmentation-fault, allocation

i am always getting  10861 segmentation fault (core dumped) in c++ sorry i came from java
it always says that head -> next how to allocate memory to that

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class Node
{
public:
  int data;
  Node *next;
};

class lisp
{
public:
  Node *head;
  void create(int d)
  {
    this->head->data = d;
    cout << head->data;
  }
  void insert(int d)
  {
    Node *n = head;
    Node *add;
    add->data = d;
    cout << head -> next << endl; 
  }
};

int main()
{
  lisp test;
  test.create(0);
  test.insert(1);
  test.insert(2);
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Pointers need to refer to valid objects. You never assign anything to `head`(or `add` for that matter), so you cannot access `head->data` either

Comment: I could imagine that enabling compiler warnings would have told you the same.

Comment: In C++ you MUST initialize variables yourself before you use them.

Comment: Some people will compile their code with compiler warnings turned off.  [Don't be like those people!](https://godbolt.org/z/ar8dx4hxn)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to initialize the pointer before assigning some values to it. So, you need `Node *add = new Node();` to do so. And suppose you want to append a new node to the list, maybe you need to keep track of the tail of the list (`Node *tail`). Every time you add a new node, you move the `tail`.

```cpp
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class Node
{
public:
  int data;
  Node *next;
};

class lisp
{
public:
  Node *head;
  Node *tail;
  void create(int d)
  {
    head = new Node();
    head->data = d;
    tail = head;
    cout << head->data << endl;
  }
  void insert(int d)
  {
    Node *add = new Node();
    add->data = d;
    add->next = NULL;
    tail->next = add;
    tail = add;
    cout << add->data << endl; 
  }
};

int main()
{
  lisp test;
  test.create(0);
  test.insert(1);
  test.insert(2);
  return 0;
}
```